# Using a string defined with \newcommand as a function argument

Tags: macros

I'm currently using LaTeX to make a poster, which is all going very nicely. However for each of the seven boxes on the poster, I've got to pass eight arguments which may change in the future. I thought a sensible thing to do would be:

```
\newcommand{\details}{textborder=roundedsmall,borderColor=black,headerborder=open,linewidth=1,boxshade=plain,boxColorOne=box,headerColorOne=head1,headerColorTwo=head2}
```

and then:

```
\headerbox{Aims}{name=aims,column=0,below=background,\details}{
    Aims
}
```

However this throws out an error

```
Package xkeyval Error: blabla (the contents of \details) undefined in families posterbox.
```

I have checked that replacing the `\details` with the contents of the custom command works fine!

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). If the answer below does not solve your issue, keep in mind that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This will also help to ensure that the proposed solution actually works for you.

Comment: @craq the original fails because `xkeyval` (following `keyval`) goes to some lengths _not_ to expand macros in its argument so that you can have a setting such as `zzz=\wibble` and the value of the value of the key is `\wibble` not the value of `\wibble` prematurely expanded while parsing the key list.

Comment: @craq Are you asking why the code in the question failed or why Dan's initial attempt to implement the answer given didn't work? (But I thought the latter was addressed in the comments.)

Comment: @cfr I was asking about the initial attempt. I agree, @DavidCarlisle's comment explains that nicely. I assume that there is no workaround, such as double-escaping e.g. `zzz=\\wibble` in the same vein as nested arguments `##1` or like shell scripts?

Comment: @craq you can pre-expand the argument see the added example (below the line) in my answer using `\edef`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks, that's another good option. It also inspired me to research more into `newcommand`, `renewcommand`, `def`, `let`, `edef` etc. I ended up with a solution similar to your original answer, but actually I don't even need to invert the call structure for my use case: TexMaker sets `[Scale=1]` as the default argument for `\includegraphics` and I change it to `[width=\textwidth]` on almost every figure. Originally I wanted to do `\newcommand{\wtw}{width=\textwidth}`, which led me here...

Comment: Now I defined `\newcommand{\includegraphicsTW}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}}` and I only have to type 2 characters instead of 16 (even less than the 4 my original attempt would have required) :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

one way is to invert the call structure:

```
\newcommand\myhead[][2]{%
\headerbox{#2}{#1,textborder=roundedsmall,borderColor=black,
               headerborder=open,linewidth=1,boxshade=plain,boxColorOne=box,
               headerColorOne=head1,headerColorTwo=head2}}


..

\myhead[name=aims,column=0,below=background]{Aims}{
    Aims
}
```

---

If you do not want to do that you need to expand `\details` before passing the keyval optional argument to the macro, one way is

```
\newcommand{\details}{textborder=roundedsmall,borderColor=black,
                       headerborder=open,linewidth=1,boxshade=plain,
                       boxColorOne=box,headerColorOne=head1,headerColorTwo=head2}

\edef\tmp{%
\noexpand\headerbox{Aims}{name=aims,column=0,below=background,\details}}
\tmp{
    Aims
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. I think it might be due to head1 and head2 being custom colours (set with \definecolor)?

Comment: @Dan David had missed an open brace. Apart from that, his code should do exactly what you seem to be asking for. Since you are not telling us what packages you are loading, it is impossible to know what "custom colours set with `\definecolor`" are (also, that would probably be a different question than this one).